# Variable undefined error

Tags: c++, undefined

I have this code in Forme_Composee.cpp

```
const Forme_Simple& getFormeSimple(int i) const
{
    return groupe[i];
}

const vector <Forme_Simple*> getGroupe() const
{
    return groupe;
}
```

And I have this in Forme_Composee.h :

```
private:
    vector <Forme_Simple*> groupe;
```

And visual tells me that the const at the end is "not allowed on non-member function" and that groupe is "undefined" but groupe is accepted by all my other functions. Please help me I didn't find any satisfying answer !

Comment: Please post the full, exact error messages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to say to which class the functions belong. Ie.
Wrong:

```
const Forme_Simple& getFormeSimple(int i) const
{
    return groupe[i];
}
```

Correct:

```
const Forme_Simple& Forme_Composee::getFormeSimple(int i) const
{
    return groupe[i];
}
```

Btw., replace `return groupe[i];` with `return *(groupe[i]);` too.

The reason for the specific error message was that the second `const` says that the function won't change any class-object-wide variables, but you defined the functions not as part of any class.

Comment: Oh my god, I am so stupid -_- Thank you very much ! I think that even it's obvious I wouldn't have found it like the classic "=" instead of "==".